# How Can I Create Button Of Full Height Inside A <td> Tag?

Tags: css

I asked A question a few days ago, that I can't increase an element's height inside `<td>` tag. Then, someone suggested me that I should try the CSS file like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Stack Overflow</title>
    <style>
        html,
        body,
        table {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }

        p {
            display: inline-table;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: chartreuse;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>Hello World</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>Hello World</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>Hello World</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>Hello World</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>Hello World</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

---

### However, it worked & works fine but it's not working for `<button>` element.

---

How can I do that for `<button>` element???

### Note That, I provided the snippet without `<button>` element

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by specifying a width and height for your `button` the same way you specified it in your `<p>` element

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Stack Overflow</title>
    <style>
        html,
        body,
        table {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }

        p {
            display: inline-table;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: chartreuse;
        }

        button {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button>Hello this is the new button</button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>Hello World</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>Hello World</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>Hello World</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>Hello World</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean that it is not working? as i can see in the snippet i provided above the button is already at the same height as your td. isnt that the problem that you need solved?

Comment: I forgot To link the css file ,,, Sorry  :(

Comment: but, when I only used button element without p element, it didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Stack Overflow</title>
    <style>
        html,
        body,
        table {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }

        button {
            display: inline-table;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: chartreuse;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
 <table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button>Hello World</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button>Hello World</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button>Hello World</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button>Hello World</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button>Hello World</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: did you change the p tag for button?